# Xcode downgrade error

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode6, xcode7

I want use two versions of Xcode (6.4 and 7). I want to use 6.4 because I want to test my app in iOS 7.1.

I use in my project the thirdparty code RMActionController(https://github.com/CooperRS/RMActionController). My problem is when I start Xcode 6.4 I have many errors. Please see the pictures. In Xcode 7 I can compile the project without any error. Can anyboyd help me?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: FYI - You can run on iOS 7 devices with Xcode 7.

Comment: What do you mean ? In the pictures above i use Xcode 6.4.   Its not possible to run iOS 7 in Xcode 7

Comment: Yes, I know. You only want to use Xcode 6.4 so you can test your app with iOS 7, right? I'm saying that if you have a real device with iOS 7 then you can use Xcode 7. This will eliminate the compiler issues and still allow you to test your code on the iOS 7 devices.

Comment: thank you. the solution is i update the code for xcode 6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the posted code requires the latest Objective-C compiler that understands things like `nullable` and generics.

There is no way to get that code to compile with the older Objective-C compiler provided with Xcode 6.x.

You have two choices since you can't use iOS 7.x simulators with Xcode 7:

1. Only use Xcode 7 and test on real devices with iOS 7.x.
2. Update the problematic code so it doesn't use any of the new Objective-C syntax. Then you can compile the code in both Xcode 6 and 7.

Comment: Thank you! i Choose number two of your solution :) i dont have a real device with ios 7.

Comment: Actually, there is a 3rd choice. Drop support for iOS 7.

Comment: Yes that Right ... This Is the 3rd Choice;) i take number 2